# Query on partitioned table on PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-10

I have a table partitioned by year.
With this query :

```
select *
from myTable
where year between '2018' and '2020'
```

the query plan is good, only 2018,2019,2020 partitions are used.

But with this query

```
select *
from myTable
where year between '2018' and extract(year from now())::text
```

the partitions 2021 and 2022 appears in the query plan, why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PostgreSQL v10, *partition pruning* (removal of unneeded partitions) can only happen at query planning time, but at that time the value of `extract(year from now())::text` is not known.

If you use PostgreSQL v11 or later, your query should perform as expected.